# Can we avoid direct page access in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

My Jquery mobile application has a simple login page through which the user will login and will be able to access the rest of the pages.But the problem here is that i am still able to access the rest of pages without logging in.The login session is maintained at client side using cookie as there is no session maintained at the server side.I have a single HTML file in which i have all the required jquery mobile pages.Is there any way that i can restrict the direct access to the internal pages of my application.

```
<body onload="init()">
  <div>
    <!--  login page -->

    <div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="wl" style="top: 1px;">
      ..............
    </div><!-- End of login page  -->
    <!--  forgot page -->

    <div data-role="page" id="forgot" data-theme="wl">
      .................
    </div><!--  End of forgot password page -->
    <!-- Search page  -->

    <div data-role="page" id="search" data-theme="wl">
      ................
    </div><!-- End of search result page  -->
    <!--  Sendmail page -->

    <div data-role="page" id="sendmail" data-theme="wl"></div>
    <!-- End of Sendmail page  -->
    <!--- View Profile Page =-->

    <div data-role="page" id="viewProfile" data-theme="wl">
      ........................
    </div><!-- End of View Profile Page  -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another simple solution.Earlier when I had this question I used to check the cookie session during the onClick event of the button click.But now I have changed it by checking the cookie session during pageshow event described below.

```
$('mypage').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
    if(checkCookie()){
        //do some task    
    } else {
       alert('Your Session has Expired or User not Logged In');
       $.mobile.changePage("#login", "slide", true, true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could prototype (override) the page show event method.

This code here is how you can handle that event:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('mypage').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
        alert('This page was just hidden: ' + ui.prevPage);
    });
</script>
```

More events can be found here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

This is a tutorial on javascript prototyping:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs2.shtml

A starting place to looking to do an override could be around the area of

> $.Event

Possibly you wouldn't even need to override an event, maybe one of the existing ones will do what you want. You can use firebug to inspect the event handler variables to see if there is a parameter option to prevent navigating to the next page.